# How to enable Spring Security Annotations not using app-Context.xml file?

Tags: spring, security, annotations

I've implemented my Application using `SecurityContextImpl` as `SecurityContext`. anything works well (Authentication and Authorization).

Now I want to use Spring Security Annotations (@Secured , ...) , I my searched result in a single comment :"USE  in your context.xml file"

is there any other way to embed security annotations using non-file-based `ContextImpls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the config snippet you need.  Not sure why you don't want to enable via XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: you know , I've got an exception :
'INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RC3
Sep 26, 2011 7:12:55 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler loadParsers
SEVERE: Failed to load required web classes
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadCla..'

Comment: I'm working on a swing standalone application , and can't understand Why I have to use org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy ?

Comment: Because Spring Security is used for web apps.  As per the intro to the documentation: "Spring Security provides comprehensive security services for J2EE-based enterprise software applications." (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/introduction.html#what-is-acegi-security).  I did find this page: http://sacrephill.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/using-spring-security-in-a-swing-desktop-application/.

Comment: another reason is : I'm using **SecurityContextImpl** and working with multiple parallel users, each one has its own Context (for authorization features) and unfortunately I don't know how to add a new **authenticated** Authentication-Object (user) to **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**

Comment: Spring main focus is on Web-Apps but **Spring Security.
Supports standalone applications, remote clients,..** [link](http://www.google.com/search?q=spring+security+standalone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: I have no other suggestions; I've never used Spring Security except in a J2EE app.  Here is a blog post which might help you: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/03/18/using-spring-security-enforce-authentication-and-authorization-spring